# how to make Full name wrap into two lines in docusign

Tags: digital-signature, docusignapi

i am new to docusign.

I am using docusign to create template and send envelope out of it. The question is, in the signature field i am using the standard tag "Full Name" for printing the recipient Name.

I have very fixed real estate horizontally. So i cannot give more space for long name rather i have the flexibility to increase the vertical spacing.

But i am not sure if i can able to make FUll Name to wrap into two lines by defining some settings.

Or are there any alternative to full name that i can create as custom tag and use it?

Thanks of reading.

Comment: (Updated my answer with additional info.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot force a `FullName` tag to line-wrap (i.e., put first name on one line and last name on the next line), but you could instead put a `FirstName` tag (on the first line) and `LastName` tag (on the next line) to force the 'line-wrap' behavior.

If you're not seeing the **FirstName** and **LastName** tags in the DocuSign UI (when dragging/dropping tags onto your template), then check **Preferences >> Features** to ensure that this setting is enabled:

[image: DS setting]

If you don't see that setting in **Preferences >> Features**, then you may need to contact DocuSign to request that they enable FirstName, LastName, and EmailAddress tags for your account.